# Adcolony unity plug in conflict with google play service plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, google-play-services, adcolony

i am working on a game on unity and i am using Play services plug in for leaderboard and facebook plugin to share the player score i got a conflict error at first when i imported both plugins but i found a solution for that. Now i imported Adcolony plugin and i got another conflict error

> Assets/AdColony/Editor/ADCDependencies.cs(10,23): error CS0433: The
>   imported type `Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport' is defined
>   multiple times
>
> Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs(146,56):
>   error CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.Dependency' is
>   defined multiple times

how can i fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this problem you need to delete PlayServicesResolver folder and importe it again from Play services plugin (not adcolony plugin!)